deploy to google cloud storage with zero downtime and github actions
I'm trying to ind a way to have a zero downtime static deploy to GCS bucket, but can't really find much resources on how to achieve this with github actions.
I currently have a deploy action which authenticates, build a nextjs application and upload to the GCS bucket using "google-github-actions/upload-cloud-storage@v2" like this
- id: upload-storage
  name: Upload build to cloud storage
  uses: google-github-actions/upload-cloud-storage@v2
  with:
    path: frontend/out
    destination: bucket-name/
    parent: false

This works well, it uploads the site into the bucket, and I believe it overwrites all the files from a previous version.
I would like to know if there is a way to do this deploy with a zero downtime.
I though of maybe creating a second folder inside to have a blue-green approach, but I can't really find much on this using github actions.
Anyone can help?
Thanks
